# Incrementing numbers in Prolog

Tags: prolog, increment

I'm trying to implement an increment in prolog, and have written the following code:

```
coordinate(X,Y,Z):- 
           X is 1, 
           Y is 1,
           Z is 1, 
           coordinate(X1,Y1,Z1), 
           X1 is X+1, 
           Y1 is Y+1, 
           Z1 is Z.
```

I also tried:

```
coordinate(X,Y,Z):-
          X is 1,
          Y is 1,
          Z is 1,
          coordinate(X+1,Y+1,X+1).
```

Neither of these work. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It's spelled coordinate.

Comment: Please be more descriptive with "not work". Is it not compiling, giving wrong results, entering an infinite loop, eating your kitten? We are not a mind reading compiler and we also have no idea what that coordinate predicate is supposed to do

Comment: What is purpose of your code? Now it will run into infinite recursion. Give us a wider context so we can understand your problem

Comment: Sorry, my code doesn't work, it compiles but does not work, and when i run it, i have to stop it using break.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither program works because they contain infinite recursion. You call `coordenate` within itself, without a stopping condition.

Then, to help you with your original problem of incrementing a variable in-place: you can't do that in Prolog. Once a variable is bound, you can't change its binding. When programming in Prolog, you have to think in terms of [relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation) and recursion, not mutable state. Here's how to increment in Prolog:

```
incr(X, X1) :-
    X1 is X+1.
```

Note that two variables are needed: one to hold the original value and one for the incremented value. To do anything useful with the computation that this predicate performs, both variables have to be arguments of the predicate. The first is meant as an input argument, the second as an output argument (though this isn't reflected in the language, it follows from the way `is/2` works).

Comment: So i fell on an infinite loop, and i need a variable that holds the value, and a variable that makes the increment. Thanks for the explanation. =)